# inserting and view sqlite database error

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-sqlite

I have a broadcastreceiver to detect incoming sms and I'm storing the sms's in sqlite database. Then I'm trying to view the database content using query. The code was working perfectly when I wasn't using "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT". After adding "id", when I try to view database content, its showing "No records found". So either its not entering values properly or there is error in view query code. I searched in other posts but not able find the error. Any help in this would be really helpful.

```css
Broadcastreceiver:

public class MyBroadcast  extends BroadcastReceiver{
 
Context mContext; 

String msg_body;    
String mob_no, name;
String dttm, key;
SQLiteDatabase db;


@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 
 db=context.openOrCreateDatabase("StudentDB", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
 
     
  Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
     if (bundle != null) {
      Object[] pdus = (Object[])bundle.get("pdus");
      final SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
      for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
         messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
       }
          StringBuffer content = new StringBuffer();
           if (messages.length > 0) {
             for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
               content.append(messages[i].getMessageBody());
               mob_no = messages[i].getOriginatingAddress();
               Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
          Date finaldate = calendar.getTime();
          dttm = finaldate.toString();  
               
             }
           }
           msg_body = content.toString();
           
           Uri lookupUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(mob_no));
           Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(lookupUri, new String[]{ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME},null,null,null);
           try {
               if(c.moveToFirst()){
                name = c.getString(0);
                
                db.execSQL("INSERT INTO student (sender, timestamp, mesg) VALUES('"+name+"','"+dttm+"','"+msg_body+"');");
               
             
                
               }else{
                
                
                db.execSQL("INSERT INTO student (sender,timestamp,mesg) VALUES('"+mob_no+"','"+dttm+"','"+msg_body+"');");
               }
               
               
           } catch (Exception e) {
               // TODO: handle exception
           }finally{
               c.close();
           }
      }
          

  

}
}
```

```html
MainActivity:

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 
 SQLiteDatabase db;
  

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     
  
  db=openOrCreateDatabase("StudentDB", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
  db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS student(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, sender TEXT, timestamp TEXT, mesg TEXT);");
  
 } //oncreate
 
 public void ViewAll(View v){
  try{
  Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM student", null);
  if(c.getCount()==0)
  {
   showMessage("Error", "No records found");
   return;
  }
  StringBuffer buffer=new StringBuffer();
  while(c.moveToNext())
  {
   buffer.append("Sender: "+c.getString(1)+"\n");
   buffer.append("TimeStamp: "+c.getString(2)+"\n");
   buffer.append("Mesg: "+c.getString(3)+"\n\n");
  }
  showMessage("Student Details", buffer.toString());
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
   System.out.println(ex.toString());
  }
 }
 
 
 public void Delete(View v){
  
  Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM student WHERE id=(SELECT MIN(id) FROM student)", null);
  if(c.moveToFirst())
  {
   db.execSQL("DELETE FROM student WHERE id=(SELECT MIN(id) FROM student)");
   showMessage("Success", "Record Deleted");
  }
  else
  {
   showMessage("Error", "Invalid Entry");
  }
 }

 private void showMessage(String title, String message) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  Builder builder=new Builder(this);
     builder.setCancelable(true);
     builder.setTitle(title);
     builder.setMessage(message);
     builder.show();
 }
 


} //activty
```

Comment: check the console in debug mode if it throws some trace of the error.

Comment: Thanks Mario. I checked and think the problem was in the cursor getstring function. I corrected the values and its working fine now.